# What is the `/` command displayed by htop?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, htop, jails

I’m running FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE on my home server.

From time to time, the server’s HDDs thrash for hours on end, even though the server itself should be idle.  (I have no cron jobs scheduled, and I killed my usual processes I run on it.)

When running `htop`, I see the following:

```
    1[                      0.0%]    2[                      0.0%]     3[                      0.0%]    4[                      0.0%]
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            1.29G/3.9G]   Tasks: 52, 0 thr; 2 running
  Swp[|                                                4.12M/512M]   Load average: 0.03 0.09 0.08
                                                                     Uptime: 4 days, 21:07:51

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
    0 root      -16   0     0  3780 S  0.0  0.1 18:34.65 kernel
47660 root       20   0  4660  2895 S  0.1  0.1  1:04.77 / /usr/jail /usr/home /var/mail /usr/src /usr/jail/storage/personal /usr/jail/storage/misc /usr/jail/storage/old /usr/jail/storage/pics /usr/jail/storage/family /usr/jail/storage/music /usr/jail/storage/docs /dev/null
 1217 ntpd       20   0  4746  4766 S  0.0  0.1  0:05.40 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/db/ntp/ntpd.pid -c /etc/ntp.conf -f /var/db/ntp/ntpd.drift
 1396 root       20   0  2816   144 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.61 /usr/sbin/cron -s
 1560 root       20   0  2806   132 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.61 /usr/sbin/cron -s
 1250 root       20   0  2832   245 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.60 /usr/sbin/cron -s
 1724 root       20   0  2806   131 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.59 /usr/sbin/cron -s
```

What’s that long command?  I suspect that’s the culprit.  `/usr/jail/storage` is the root dir of my `storage` jail, and all of the directories listed (`personal`, `misc`, `old`, `pics`, `family`, `music`, `docs`) are various zfs filesystems on those HDDs.

Comment: `lsof -p 47660` would likely tell you more as to what it is.

Comment: This is FreeBSD.  The correct command would be `procstat -c 47660`, not `lsof`.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell for sure, but I'd guess it's the `updatedb` process for `locate` - running `find / ...` to build its database.

Do you have `locate`, `slocate`, `mlocate`, `plocate` or similar installed?   Do you use it often enough to justify the daily update?

BTW, if you don't want to disable it entirely (and don't mind locate's db being even more out of date), you can change the cron job to run every 2 or 3 days, or weekly.

Also, depending on which locate implementation you have, you can probably configure it to ignore certain directories by editing `/etc/updatedb.conf`

---

If it's not `updatedb`, try running `ps waux | grep jail` (or one of the other directories you can see in `htop`.  That should give you the full command name, un-shortened by htop.   And if you have `pstree` installed, use that to see the process tree that resulted in whatever is running.

Comment: The `ps` command has a `-d` option.  And `ps` in general takes getopt-style options.  There is no need for `pstree`, and `-waux` is the syntax per the manual.